# Problem with WooCommerce plugin view problem

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm writing to you because I have a problem with a WooCommerce plugin, it's called auction WooCommerce, I've been working a lot and I can't figure out how to center the elements but at the same time, they start from the left.
I leave you a screenshot of the problem and I attach the code I am using.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:350px) {
  .woocommerce ul.products li.product,
  .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    width: 40.05%!important;
  }
}

.woocommerce ul.products {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: left;
}
```

[Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEBrm.jpg)

Comment: People can help you if you can show us the link or recreate a demo of the code.

Comment: si, perfecto el codigo es el que puse anteriormente, pude centrar los productos pero no consigo alinearlos a la izquierda.

link:https://inmobiliariaversacci.com.ar/remates/

Comment: Are you looking to center all of them like the first element? https://nimb.ws/J86HZV